# jQuery ticker with option to start in random order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a ticker to start with a random point and run the rest of list items from there. e.g. if it starts with 3, then runs 4, 5 ... afterwards.

I found a jQuery plugin with a random option, but it doesn't work like that. Can someone help me to modify it please?

There are two examples below: 1. Normal order. 2. Random order (it is the one that I'm trying to modify, right now it runs in the random order for the entire list).

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2d7q8dp/)**

```js
// Plugin
(function($) {
  $.fn.list_ticker = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
      speed: 4000,
      effect: 'slide',
      run_once: false,
      random: false
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {

      var obj = $(this);
      var list = obj.children();
      var count = list.length - 1;

      list.not(':first').hide();

      var interval = setInterval(function() {

        list = obj.children();
        list.not(':first').hide();

        var first_li = list.eq(0)
        var second_li = options.random ? list.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)) : list.eq(1)

        if (first_li.get(0) === second_li.get(0) && options.random) {
          second_li = list.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length));
        }

        if (options.effect == 'slide') {
          first_li.slideUp();
          second_li.slideDown(function() {
            first_li.remove().appendTo(obj);

          });
        } else if (options.effect == 'fade') {
          first_li.fadeOut(function() {
            obj.css('height', second_li.height());
            second_li.fadeIn();
            first_li.remove().appendTo(obj);
          });
        }

        count--;

        if (count == 0 && options.run_once) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }

      }, options.speed)
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

// Custom
(function($) {
  $('#order').list_ticker();

  $('#random').list_ticker({
    random: true
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>Normal order</b>
<ul id="order">
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Third Item</li>
  <li>Fourth Item</li>
  <li>Fifth Item</li>
</ul>

<b>Random order</b>
<ul id="random">
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Third Item</li>
  <li>Fourth Item</li>
  <li>Fifth Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a bit your plugin in order to have an index and increment it instead to remove and append li at the end of your ul.

```js
// Plugin
(function($) {
    $.fn.list_ticker = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            speed: 4000,
            effect: 'slide',
            run_once: false,
            random: false
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {

            var obj = $(this);
            var list = obj.children();
            var count = list.length - 1;

            //
            // added the idx variable
            //
            var first_liIdx = 0;
            if (options.random) {
                first_liIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
                options.random = false;
            }
            list.not(':eq(' + first_liIdx + ')').hide();


            var interval = setInterval(function() {

                list = obj.children();

                //
                // act on idx instead of removing and appeding li
                //
                var nextIdx = (first_liIdx +1) % list.length;
                var first_li = list.eq(first_liIdx)
                var second_li = list.eq(nextIdx);


                if (options.effect == 'slide') {
                    first_li.slideUp();
                    second_li.slideDown();
                } else if (options.effect == 'fade') {
                    first_li.fadeOut(function() {
                        obj.css('height', second_li.height());
                        second_li.fadeIn();
                    });
                }

                count--;

                first_liIdx = nextIdx;

                if (count == 0 && options.run_once) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }

            }, options.speed)
        });
    };
})(jQuery);


$('#order').list_ticker();

$('#random').list_ticker({
    random: true
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<b>Normal order</b>
<ul id="order">
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
    <li>Fourth Item</li>
    <li>Fifth Item</li>
</ul>

<b>Random order</b>
<ul id="random">
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
    <li>Fourth Item</li>
    <li>Fifth Item</li>
</ul>
```

If, instead, you want to preserve the **random** option and the remove/append behavior you can:

- add a new option:  randomOnlyAtStart
- at the beginning if this option is true you need to compute a random value and remove plus append all the first random lis.

Change this line:

```
list.not(':first').hide();
```

to:

```
if (options.randomOnlyAtStart) {
    list = obj.children();
    var randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
    for(var i=0; i<randomIdx; i++) {
        list.eq(i).remove().appendTo(obj);
    }
    list = obj.children();
}
```

```js
// Plugin
(function($) {
    $.fn.list_ticker = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            speed: 4000,
            effect: 'slide',
            run_once: false,
            random: false,
            randomOnlyAtStart: false
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {

            var obj = $(this);
            var list = obj.children();
            var count = list.length - 1;

            //
            // next if block added
            //
            if (options.randomOnlyAtStart) {
                list = obj.children();
                var randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
                for(var i=0; i<randomIdx; i++) {
                    list.eq(i).remove().appendTo(obj);
                }
                list = obj.children();
            }
            list.not(':first').hide();

            var interval = setInterval(function() {

                list = obj.children();
                list.not(':first').hide();

                var first_li = list.eq(0)
                var second_li = options.random ? list.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)) : list.eq(1)

                if (first_li.get(0) === second_li.get(0) && options.random) {
                    second_li = list.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length));
                }

                if (options.effect == 'slide') {
                    first_li.slideUp();
                    second_li.slideDown(function() {
                        first_li.remove().appendTo(obj);

                    });
                } else if (options.effect == 'fade') {
                    first_li.fadeOut(function() {
                        obj.css('height', second_li.height());
                        second_li.fadeIn();
                        first_li.remove().appendTo(obj);
                    });
                }

                count--;

                if (count == 0 && options.run_once) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }

            }, options.speed)
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#order').list_ticker();

$('#random').list_ticker({
    randomOnlyAtStart: true
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<b>Normal order</b>
<ul id="order">
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
    <li>Fourth Item</li>
    <li>Fifth Item</li>
</ul>

<b>Random order</b>
<ul id="random">
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
    <li>Fourth Item</li>
    <li>Fifth Item</li>
</ul>
```